# When I build app on Xcode from unity ,I am Getting _ShowToast Error on Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_showToast", referenced from:
      _RewardedVideoAdCaller_WatchRewardedVideo_m2466777805 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
      _WatchVideo_CallRewardedAd_m1203001618 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
      _ToastHelper_ShowToast_m4121784244 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
      _ToastExample_Toast_m2732689691 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
      _ToastHelper_showToast_m1229755728 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
      _WatchVideo_AdCallbackhanler_m1904289898 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
     (maybe you meant: _ToastMessage_showToastOnUiThread_m388594658, _ToastMessage_showToast_m4105793716_MetadataUsageId , _ToastMessage_showToast_m4105793716 , _ToastHelper_showToast_m1229755728 , _ToastMessage_showToastOnUiThread_m388594658_MetadataUsageId , _ToastMessage_showToast_m4105793716_RuntimeMethod_var )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Image of _ShowToast error on xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlKfr.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for others to help you better, please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple fixes to your issue. I recommend you try each of them.

1. In Unity 2017, turning on Analytics and/or Unity Ads sometimes causes this error when building in Xcode.
2. Check that the "Plugins" folder imported from the Google AdMob package is there and complete. If not then delete and re-import the package.
3. Instead of opening your .xcodeproj file, open the .workspace one. By default, the Google AdMob package set the CocoaPods in the .workspace file, thus opening the .xcodeproj won't load them properly and causes a linker command failure. You can change that in your Unity settings for Google AdMob.